# SharePoint calculated formula syntax error

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation

Good Morning,

I'm trying to create an element/column with the formula `=IF([Present]=TRUE,"Complete","Incomplete")` 
but at my SharePoint I can never edit formulas with "IF". 
Always give syntax error!

Someone can help me ?
Thanks!
[image: erreur saving formula - syntax erreur but the formula is correct i think...]

Comment: Are you able to create calculated columns in another list in same site? What is the data type of your "Present" column?

Answer (score 0):

Please try this one:

=IF([Present]=TRUE;"Complete";"Incomplete")

*If this solves your issue, please mark as answer.*

Answer (score 0):

Try using below formula:

```
=IF([Present]=TRUE,"Complete","Incomplete")
```

**Note**:

Sometimes comma(`,`) does not work in formula (I am not sure but it is based on something language on your site). So in that case use semicolon(`;`) instead of comma(`,`), like:

```
=IF([Present]=TRUE;"Complete";"Incomplete")
```

**Official documentations**:

1. [Calculated Field Formulas](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/bb862071(v%3Doffice.14)).
2. [IF function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/if-function-7025be14-5665-43d0-af20-8293d1fe9d3a).

Comment: Thanks a lot!!!! Have a nice day!

Comment: Welcome. as this answer helped you, please [accept it as an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).